# SensorEventListener in combination with Timer-Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, sensors, countdown

I want to write an Android program which lets the user set up a countdown timer. After the user pushes the "Start-Button" the countdown is running. While the countdown is running, the phone should recognize the acceleration of the device.

If time is up, or the device was shaken to much a new activity should be loaded..

At my device (S4) the code is running quite well, only the countdown timer doesn't get closed after the device has been shaken to much, so the run-method will be activated suddenly. On other device (S2) the new activity is started directly after pushing the button. How could this be?
I think I made a mistake with the run-method and I am not sure if I understand the idea about setting threads correctly.

Here is my code:

```
public class WaitingForBomb extends Activity {

float sensibility = 2.5f;
boolean isOver = false;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private float mAccel; // Beschleunigung
private float mAccelCurrent; // aktuelle Beschleunigung (in Verbindung mit
                                // Erdanziehung)?
private float mAccelLast; // letzte Beschleunigung (in Verbindung mit
                            // Erdanziehung)?
TextView anzeige;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.waiting);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mAccel = 0.00f;
    mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
    mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

    // Sleep-Timer
    Thread bombTimer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (isOver = false) {
                try {
                    // Intent-Übergabe des Counters
                    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
                    int counterValue = mIntent
                            .getIntExtra("pushCounter", 0);
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    v.vibrate(counterValue);
                    sleep(counterValue);

                    isOver = true;

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    isOver = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    bombTimer.start();

}

// Verhindert, dass die "Back-Taste" erkannt wird und somit das Spiel
// vorzeitig beendet wird.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
        float x = se.values[0];
        float y = se.values[1];
        float z = se.values[2];
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter

        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean checkSense1 = getPrefs.getBoolean("sensi1", true);
        boolean checkSense2 = getPrefs.getBoolean("sensi2", false);

        if (checkSense1 == true) {
            sensibility = 1.25f;
        }

        if (checkSense2 == true) {
            sensibility = 0.75f;
        }

        // Prüft die Beschleunigung
        if (mAccel > sensibility) {
            Intent gameOver = new Intent("android.intent.action.BOOM");
            startActivity(gameOver);
        }
        if (isOver == true) {
            Intent gameOver = new Intent("android.intent.action.BOOM");
            startActivity(gameOver);
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just update your while condition**

```
while (!isOver) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solved my problem. Now the new activity gets started after pushing back-button to close the activity (app). Have I to set up isOver = true at other position(s)?